# Karl Popper critiques to historical relativism

Tags: reference-request, popper, relativism

In his book "In Search of a Better World", Popper says that he already have argued against historical and social relativism in other works. What are these others works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find Popper's most scathing critiques in his [The Open Society and Its Enemies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Open_Society_and_Its_Enemies) (1945, 2 vol.) and [The Poverty of Historicism](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Poverty_of_Historicism) (1957).